# Stop MoveClip with Button [Flash - ActionScript 2]

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2, movieclip

I need to create a MovieClip that is looping, and when I press a button it stops but let the animation finish.

This is my code:
On (release) {movieClipName.gotoAndStop(60);}

This almost works for me because it goes to the last frame (60) but it doesn’t let the animation finish. And if I write stop(); on the last frame it does not loop in the beginning.
Any ideas?
I am NOT allowed to use functions, variables or conditionals.

My project https://www.dropbox.com/s/t68vde8qocq7spa/Square%20and%20Button.fla?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This not work ?

On (release) {movieClipName.stop();}

or you need in last frame?

**UPD**

i don't know what's wrong, but in my [simple project](http://cl.ly/1I2u0F1g3Z3s) all work fine;

**UPD 2.10.14**

ok next try [this](http://cl.ly/2E3P012i3q0I)

Comment: I need it in the last frame.

Comment: Ok i load my simple project

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted but thank you anyways! I have uploaded my project if you want to take a look. I just need to tell flash that I want to wait until the animation finish to stop, or do some kind of trick... it's a class exercise and the teacher said it's tricky so don't worry, and thanks again!